# ggplot producing stacked bar when expecting a dodge chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a data set showing product, fiscal period and transactions in one table.

```
app$FISCAL_PERIOD <-(201604,201604,201604,201605,201605,201605,201606,201606,201606,201607,201607,201607,201608,201608,201608,201609,201609,201610,201610,201611,201611)

app$Product <- c("Product 1","Product 3","Other","Product 1","Product 3","Other","Product 1","Product 3","Other","Product 1","Product 3","Other","Product 1","Product 3","Other","Product 2","Product 3","Product 2","Product 3","Product 2","Product 3")

app$sum_trans<-c(78,23410,1946,84,29532,417,16,30364,129,305,32386,584,424,20873,274,20,20929,470,19261,10,6131)
```

When I run this, I get the chart I was hoping for, a "dodged" bar chart:

`ggplot(data=app, aes(x=FISCAL_PERIOD, y=sum_trans, fill=Product)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black")`

But when I run this I get a stacked bar chart which is not what I need:

`ggplot(data=app, aes(x=Product, y=sum_trans, fill=FISCAL_PERIOD)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(), colour="black")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be the case because ggplot does not understand FISCAL_PERIOD variable as a factor variable. This should do the fix:

```
ggplot(data=app, aes(x=Product, y=sum_trans, fill=as.factor(FISCAL_PERIOD))) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", colour="black")
```